# Can't parse JSON with JQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm trying to create an autocomplete text box using VB .Net4.  It has a json back-end that simply returns a first name and last name, like so:

```
{"d":"[{\"firstN\":\"john\",\"lastN\":\"doe\"},{\"firstN\":\"another \",\"lastN\":\"dude\"},{\"firstN\":\"dsaf\",\"lastN\":\"asdfasdf\"}]"}
```

My JQuery seems like a pretty standard bit of code:

```
$("#MainContent_autocomplete").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/PatientLookup.asmx/LookupPatient",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "{ 'key': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        processData: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {                                
                                    label: item.firstN,
                                    value: item.firstN
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
```

The problem occurs in the success function.  When it gets inside the map function it simply will not let me read the firstN and lastN data.

Comment: Are you sure that the returned jSon is valid? I think that it comes from the double quotes before and after the square brackets.

Comment: Please use the ASP.NET tag, not "asp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the quoted array, it looks like you're returning a string value that you've manually JSON serialized using JavaScriptSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer, like:

```
public string LookupPatient(string key) {
  // Something that returns a string of JSON here.
}
```

Is that right?

If so, you should let .NET handle the serialization for you.  Like this:

```
public class Name {
  public string firstN { get; set; }
  public string lastN { get; set; }
}

public List<Name> LookupPatient(string key) {
  List<Name> result = new List<Name>();

  result.Add(new Name() { firstN = "Dave", lastN = "Ward" });
  result.Add(new Name() { firstN = "John", lastN = "Doe" });

  // JSON serialization happens automatically here.
  return result;
}
```

If you already have an appropriate view model or DTO class, obviously you can reuse that instead of creating the `Name` class specifically for this one method.

Comment: Thanks Dave !!  You nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid: `d`'s value must not be quoted, and you're escaping the quotes:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "firstN": "john"
            , "lastN": "doe"
        }
        , {
            "firstN": "another"
            , "lastN" : "dude"
        }
        , {
            "firstN": "dsaf",
            "lastN": "asdfasdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was the format which the >net serializer spit out.  I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @harold: Are you using .NET's [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)? I used it once some time ago and it worked well.